Unable to Insert data from s3 to DDB using Glue
While writing data to DDB after reading from s3, It is failing with the belowe mentioned error:
Error Category: UNCLASSIFIED_ERROR; An error occurred while calling o112.pyWriteDynamicFrame. Provided list of item keys contains duplicates (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: K1F7N8KUCE2Q4QMBT8EF6CCM57VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
My script is as follows :
import sys
import boto3 
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

def sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glueContext, transformation_ctx)
    
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

# Initialize the DynamoDB client
dynamodb_client = boto3.client('dynamodb')

# Define the DynamoDB table name
dynamodb_table_name = "TABLE_NAME"


# Script generated for node Amazon S3
AmazonS3_node1712735773212 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    format_options={}, 
    connection_type="s3", 
    format="parquet", 
    connection_options={"paths": ["S3_PATH"], "recurse": True,
    "exclusions" : ["SPECIFIC_S3_PATH"]},
    transformation_ctx="AmazonS3_node1712735773212")

# Create the DynamoDB table if it doesn't exist
try:
    dynamodb_client.create_table(
        TableName=dynamodb_table_name,
        KeySchema=[
             {'AttributeName': 'ATT1', 'KeyType': 'HASH'},  # Assuming artist_dmid is the partition key
            {'AttributeName': 'ATT2', 'KeyType': 'RANGE'} 
            
        ],
        AttributeDefinitions=[
            {'AttributeName': 'ATT1', 'AttributeType': 'N'}, 
            {'AttributeName': 'ATT2', 'AttributeType': 'N'},
        ],
        BillingMode= 'PAY_PER_REQUEST'
    )
    print(f"DynamoDB table '{dynamodb_table_name}' created successfully.")
except dynamodb_client.exceptions.ResourceInUseException:
    print(f"DynamoDB table '{dynamodb_table_name}' already exists.")


# Script generated for node SQL Query
SqlQuery0 = '''
select DISTINCT ATT1,ATT2,ATT3,ATT4 from myDataSource

'''
SQLQuery_node1712736016679 = sparkSqlQuery(glueContext, query = SqlQuery0, mapping = {"myDataSource":AmazonS3_node1712735773212}, transformation_ctx = "SQLQuery_node1712736016679")

# SelectFields_node1711627341244 = SelectFields.apply(
#     frame=AmazonS3_node1712735773212,
#     paths=[
#         "ATT1",
#         "ATT2",
#         "ATT3",
#         "ATT4",
#     ],
#     transformation_ctx="SelectFields_node1711627341244",
# )

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=SQLQuery_node1712736016679 ,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={ "dynamodb.region": "us-east-1","dynamodb.output.tableName": dynamodb_table_name,
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)

job.commit()

How can I update the above script to filter out duplicate items from the list , on some condition, before adding those items to DDB?

You already have the SELECT DISTINCT query but the important part that's missing is that it must be based on the tables keys only, you include a third and fourth attribute.
